# What is the best way to mimic a search query within a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, search

I'm in the process of building a Wordpress plugin. I wish to mimic WP's default search functionality but in the form of a 'live search'.

I have my JS setup to grab the query string (i.e what would be `/?s=search-term`) & am passing it via AJAX to my function. But now I have to process the query to get the list of posts & pages. But I've read that it's not right to simply use `query_post` from the [WP documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

So my question is, **what is the correct approach to yield the same search results as if the default search form was submitted?**

Please can someone provide a code snippet or a link to a detailed article which clarifies this for me.

Thanks & please pardon my nativity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the 's' parameter to a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object.

```
$mys = new WP_Query(
  array(
    's' => 'whatever',
  )
);
```

That should duplicate the default search.

Comment: Well that was easier than I first thought! Thanks.